# I can't connect my IDE to org using SFDX:Authorize command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When I use `SFDX:Authorize` org command, it redirects me to Salesforce login screen. Then I enter my credentials. However I see only white screen and there is no response. From my home machine everything works fine. My OS - Linux Mint 20.

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/834 You can try with an other default browser too

Comment: i've tryed with Chrome and Mozila. It have not worked either

Comment: seems like a known issue here https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/864

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded my sfdx-cli to 7.76 and everything is ok now. But all versions after 7.76 make connection to org impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a known issue on the Salesforce CLI being reported using many different related issues on the open-source tooling repo of Salesforce

[Running SFDX: Authorize an Org keeps running and never connected to Org](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2996)

[VSCode Authorize an Org freeze in RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/2931)

[sfdx force:auth:web:login not working but sfdx auth:web:login is working](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/864)

The current workaround is to use either of the approaches

1. Downgrade the Salesforce DX plugin to a lower version using `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@50.1.0` works for many.
2. Use the `sfdx auth:login` as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_web_flow.htm) instead of using `sfdx force:auth:login`